# How to display field name from MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to display field names from a MySQL query using PHP. I'm not getting anything to display when I print the field name into an HTML table and I'm not sure if this is how I should be going about getting the field names. Here is my code:

```
$i = 0;
while( $i < mysqli_num_fields($result)){
$field_names = mysqli_fetch_fields($result);
echo "<th>$field_names->name</th>";
$i++;}
```

Comment: Can you please specify if there are any errors returned by mysqli or what you've done to debug it?

Comment: I'm not sure how I could check for errors with mysqli. If I remove ->name from the back of the field_names I will have "Array" printed as the value, which lines up with fetch_fields returning an array. If I knew how to display the name from that array I think that would fix the issue, but i haven't found a way of doing it that works

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_fields()` returns an array of objects, not an object.

Try replacing the above mentioned code, with the following, this should work:

```
$fields=mysqli_fetch_fields($result);
foreach ($fields as $field) echo "<th>$field->name</th>";
```

or use the singular version of the function `mysqli_fetch_field()` in your original code.

For more information on how mysqli_fetch_fields work, check out the official documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried something similar to this earlier, but it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

It is better to use `mysql_fetch_array()`

```
while( $data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<th>$data['name']</th>";
}
```